# suddenly wifi internet disconnection

Tags: linux, wifi, lmde, halt

I have sometimes internet disconnection from my wifi connection to my home wifi modem.

I have one Linux LMDE OS into my Lenovo IdeaPad 310 laptop, so in regular times I have this:

```
so@notebook:~$  uname -a
Linux notebook 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1 (2019-04-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux



  so@notebook:~$ ifconfig           

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500 
       inet 192.168.1.105  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255 
       inet6 fe80::59dc:548c:4eb2:a3e5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link> 
       ether c8:3d:d4:3c:23:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet) 
       RX packets 50050  bytes 46065327 (43.9 MiB) 
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0 
       TX packets 40256  bytes 6564953 (6.2 MiB) 
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

but when my wifi internet disconnected I have this:

```
so@notebook:~$ ifconfig           
wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500 
       inet6 fe80::59dc:548c:4eb2:a3e5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link> 
       ether c8:3d:d4:3c:23:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet) 
       RX packets 50203  bytes 46102351 (43.9 MiB) 
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0 
       TX packets 40387  bytes 6581340 (6.2 MiB) 
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and my wifi setting could be seen here:
[image: my wifi setting]

**Update:**
Based on comments I have:

```
so@notebook:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
        Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
        Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
03:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 920MX] [10de:134f] (rev a2)
```

So why this happened?

Comment: Welcome, could you add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` .

Comment: I have added to my question ...

Comment: Is this the same question as [your earlier one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/523957/100397)?